# Array ( [uname] => root [pword] => root ) error in php login

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a php login however i am getting this error Array ( [uname] => root ) i have a user_table with two elements in the table called username and password

bellow is my code

```
<form name="input" action="Log_in_validation.php" method="POST">

<label for="User_name" >Username:</label>
<input name="uname" input id="uname" type="text" title="enter username"/>

  <label for="Password" >Password: </label>
<input name="pword" input id="pword" type="password" title="enter password"/>

<input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
```

php code for login validation

```
<?php
session_start();
 print_r($_POST);
 $errmsg_arr = array();
 $errflag = false;
 // configuration
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "PolyTest";
 $dbuser        = "root";
 $dbpass        = "root";

// database connection
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass); //The     connection is eastiblist

// new data

$user = $_POST['uname'];
$password = $_POST['pword'];
if($user == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Please enter your Username';
$errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Please enter your Password';
$errflag = true;
}
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE username= :hjhjhjh   AND password= :asas");
$result->bindParam(':hjhjhjh', $user);
$result->bindParam(':asas', $password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($rows > 0) {
header('location: '. $_POST['url']); //Here the URL is instered so that the user is taken to the pervioulsy viewed page.
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user;

}
else{
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Could not find Login Deatils ';
$errflag = true;
}
if($errflag) { 
$_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
session_write_close();
header("location: Login.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Storing passwords as plaintext? Bad...very bad.

Answer (score 4):

same `name` for both inputs?? and same `id`

name should be unique for different fields, 
Even `id`(same page cannot have an id multiple times).

```
<input name="uname" id="uname" type="text" title="enter username"/>

<input name="pword" id="pword" type="password" title="enter password"/>
            ^    ^     ^     ^
```

**Change name and id for password field**

Comment: can you add that in your question??